# How do I assign values to items in a list?

Tags: python

I'm unable to determine an easy way to have a list with values assigned to each item in the list, where when an item is called the value will be printed.

I've tried to use tuples in a list, such as `foo = [('bar', 1), ('baz', 2)]`, and then calling `foo[1]`, but instead of doing `2`, it goes `('baz', 2)`.

```
>>> foo = [('bar', 1), ('baz', 2)]`
>>> foo[1]
or
>>> foo[1[1]]
```

Neither seems to work.  The former calling method emits `(baz, 2)` and the latter produces an error.

Is there a different way to do this?  Or is this correct, but I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: are you looking for a dictionary?

Comment: @aws_apprentice, I do not understand.

Comment: it sounds like you need to use a dictionary instead of a list

Comment: [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are designed to associate keys to values, whereas lists simply store data in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
foo[1][1]
```

This will give you second element of the list, and second element of your tuple.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.